# Dynamic Font Size based on user input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i try to build a component where a user types into a input field and the font size needs to resize dynamically while typing to fit the outer div but when i remove characters it jumps out of the outer div. I understand why but i can't find a way to solve it.

Also it looks like i have a little too much if statements. Is there a way to make it more elegant?

```html
<script setup>
  import { ref, watch } from "vue";

  const names = ref("Jane & John Doe");
  let fontSize = ref(40);
  let maxFontSize = ref(120);
  const title = ref();
  const innerTitle = ref();

  watch(names, async (newNames, oldNames) => {
    if (newNames.length === 0) {
      fontSize.value = maxFontSize.value;
    }

    if (
      newNames.length >= oldNames.length &&
      innerTitle.value.clientWidth + 100 >= title.value.clientWidth
    ) {
      fontSize.value -= 20;
    }

    if (
      newNames.length <= oldNames.length &&
      innerTitle.value.clientWidth + 100 <= title.value.clientWidth
    ) {
      fontSize.value < maxFontSize.value
        ? (fontSize.value += 20)
        : console.log("nothin");
    }

    if (
      newNames.length <= oldNames.length &&
      innerTitle.value.clientWidth + 100 >= title.value.clientWidth
    ) {
      fontSize.value -= 20;
    }
  });
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="names" />
  <div size="A4">
    <div ref="title" style="background: green" class="title">
      <div
        ref="innerTitle"
        style="
          background: blue;
          width: auto;
          height: auto;
          display: inline-block;
        "
        :style="`font-size: ${fontSize}pt`"
      >
        {{ names }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  body {
    background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  }

  div {
    background: red;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things by disregarding whether your `newName.length` is > or < the `oldName.length` and instead set a lower and upper bound for the space you want your text to fill. For example, if the text uses less than 50% of the container space, increase the font size, but if it uses greater than 80% of the space, decrease the font size.  Any amount of space between 50% and 80% results in no change.

```js
const resizeText = () => {
  if (
    innerTitle.value.clientWidth <= title.value.clientWidth * 0.5 &&
    fontSize.value < maxFontSize.value
  ) {
    fontSize.value += 5;
  } else if (
    innerTitle.value.clientWidth > title.value.clientWidth * 0.8 &&
    fontSize.value > 10
  ) {
    fontSize.value -= 5;
  }
};
```

```html
<input v-model="names" @input="resizeText" />
```

You just have to watch out for changing the fontSize so much that it immediately bounces back and forth between being > 80% and < 50% with each fontSize change.  I think +/- 5pt. at a time works well.

Comment: This works very nice, thank you! Only thing, when i delete characters, the font size isn't going back to the starting value even if it fits in to the box.